# How can SR-Latches store data over time?

Tags: latch, sequential-logic

My understanding is that the *storing* part of SR-latches boils down to having a wire loop. Ostensibly, the idea is that if there was current in the loop a second ago, there will still be current in the loop now. The S/R inputs just allow us to control whether or not there is current in said loop.

What I don't understand is this:

- How can a loop with current be allowed? Isn't the current just going to heat up the wire a bit and then vanish? How can it keep the data "forever"?
- If we want to read the loop's "data", how come the current doesn't

  1. vanish from the loop after, or
  2. just stay in the loop and not be readable, since the loop offers no resistance

All of this would of course be resolved if there was some power source replenishing current when current is needed, but then we'd also have to make sure that it doesn't add current when no current is desired. No material I could find discussed the source of power, anyhow.

As a total newbie to sequential circuits, any help / clarifications would really be very helpful, and much appreciated.

Comment: An SR latch is not a simple wire loop (with or without resistance) - it's [active circuitry](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Digital_Circuits/Latches) that maintains and reinforces a signal until such time as an external stimulus sets or resets the latch.

Comment: No current loop. They have positive feedback, which is a form of loopback. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)

Comment: Gates in textbooks are often drawn individually in schematics; it is assumed they have appropriate power sources.  On actual product schematics, one gate in a multigate IC might have a power connection that services the rest, or often the power connections are shown as a separate part.

Comment: Following the link to the Wikipedia article on flip-flops, the implementation there provides a voltage output at the collector (upper node) of transistor Q2 and an inverted output at the collector of transistor Q1.  The source of power in the figure is the upper voltage rail (marked +V).  The power is dissipated by the transistor whose collector is at a low voltage.  The other transistor does not conduct.  Usually the resistances are large enough that you can neglect their power dissipation.  What you do not want to do is close both switches at the same time to avoid invalid outputs.

Comment: @nanofarad & co.: Thank you! This ([positive feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_feedback#In_electronics)) is what I've been missing—in particular, I just realized/remembered that logic gates already act as amplifiers of low/high signals themselves (the whole noise margins thing). Also clears up my confusion about why cross-coupled inverters, and not just a wire loop, is used as an introductory example of a bistable circuit (though I suppose cross-coupled buffers could also work?).

Comment: @Charles B. Cameron: I have to admit, I don't really understand that diagram: where are the loops? Should the switches be thought of as normally open push switches/buttons? Where do we read the data, Q, from?